# how to get variable in dag from airflow secrets

Tags: airflow, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I'm trying to understand how to use secrets in Airflow.

I've configured hashicorp vault as a secret backend in airflow and put there an variable like:

```
AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND: "airflow.contrib.secrets.hashicorp_vault.VaultBackend"
AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS: '{"url":"http://vault:8200","token":My_TOKEN_TO_VAULT,"variables_path":"variables","mount_point":"airflow","connections_path":"connections"}'
    
1 docker exec -it VAULT_DOCKER_ID sh
2 vault login My_TOKEN_TO_VAULT
3 vault secrets enable -path=airflow -version=2 kv
4 vault kv put airflow/variables/slack_token value=SOMETHING
```

Now i'm trying to use this variable in my dag

Simple Variable.get('slack_token') indeed works but when I try to use it to connect with Slack i get an error.
So in process of debugging I noticed that this variable is printed as "***" so I suppose it is encrypted.

How to get an access to it?

Thanks :)